# mediaplayer failing on R.raw - Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Importing `import android.media.MediaPlayer`, I am told `raw cannot be resolved` in

```
 private void playSound(){
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Jam);
...
```

I am really new to `Android`, what is `raw` for ? and how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777413/android-raw-folders-creation-and-reference. /res/raw/Jam.mp3

Comment: If you have raw folder the file name cant be in capital letter, rename it to jam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A raw folder holds files of any type. You need a `raw` folder under your resources folder (`res`).  In your example, `jam` is expected as a resource in the `raw` folder, and will likely be a type of music file as you're using `MediaPlayer` to try and read it.

You've this error `raw cannot be resolved` because raw folder doesn't exist, and so the variable `raw` in class `R` is not being auto-generated.

Fix the problem by creating the `raw` folder.

If you already have created `res/raw` try cleaning the project. Sometimes Eclipse gets confused. If that doesn't work, make a small change to a source file, and save it so the auto-build process kicks off. Sometimes cleaning manually hasn't fixed the problem for me, its a known bug for Eclipse.

Comment: Sure I had this raw folder withe the mp3 file inside. In fact, I restarted my ide (`Android Studio`) and it worked ;)

Comment: Great! Yeah these auto-generation tools sometimes have synchronization problems with IDE's. Please accept an answer to close the question @Newben

Answer (score 4):

"raw" is a (or should be) a folder in your Android Project, containing the file "Jam" in your case. ("Jam" will most likely be a .wav or .mp3 file)

Since "raw" cannot be resolved you probably do not have a folder called "raw" in your project.
In order to get rid of the error create a folder called "raw" in your Android Project folder.

> I am not 100% sure about this but I am also quite sure that files inside the "raw" folder cannot contain
>   CAPITAL letters. (only a-z0-9)

Comment: Sure I had this folder and the file inside, but I had to restart my ide and it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to right-click on res->new->Android resource directory.
- Select raw in resource type and it automatically selects raw as the
  directory name.
- Drag and drop your .mp3 music file inside the res folder. Make sure that it starts with a small letter.