# Method parameters in android

Tags: android, methods, parameters

Is it possible to have parameters of a method in android to be the value for R.raw.parametervalue, for example;

```
public void sound(SOMETHING sound){

m = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);

}
```

Comment: yes it is possible, as R.raw.sound is an int. So your method signature will have (Context context, Int soundId)

Comment: @Darpan, You should post it as answer, it´s correct...

Comment: it says sound cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I answered your this problem in my answer, check. Thanks for pointing @Opiatefuchs (took me a minute to write your username)

Comment: :) yes it´s a not usual name :)

Comment: @Android, could You please update Your code above so that we can see where the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is possible, as `R.raw.sound` is an `int`. So your method signature will have

`(Context context, Int soundID)`

For sound is not getting recognized, you need to create sound file in 'raw' folder, this problem is mentioned here - 
[Check this one out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18134421/609782)

Comment: I have created a raw folder with the sounds

Answer (score 2):

use it:

```
public void sound(int soundResource){

m = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundResource);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id and retrieve raw file from resources using id.

Example:

```
public void sound (int soundId) {
    AssetFileDescriptor aFileDesc = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundId);
    m = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundId);
    //do something
}
```

Hope this helps.