# Play a sound in android

Tags: android, audio

How do I make an android app which just plays a sound on click of a button ?
Suppose, a sound file a.mp3 is inside res\sound\
How should I play it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to create a folder called [`raw`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308338/4385913) then put there the music you want to play and then do something like this :

```
 public class TestSound extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btSound = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musicTest);
        btSound .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });     
    }
```

[Supported Media FormatsAndroid](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Hope it works :)

Comment: Does it play all the sounds in raw folder ??

Comment: What do you mean? It plays the music that you choose on `R.raw.`

Comment: You made my day. Thanks :D

Comment: @HelloWorld I've eddited my question to show you the supported media formats on Android. If my answer helped to you don't forget to upvote/mark it as a correct ^^ Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87395/discussion-between-hello-world-and-skizo).

Comment: do you need more help @HelloWorld?