# How to acess new created folder in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, directory

I created a folder in res folder and it named draw2 which i will use for specisific imageviews.I want to access the images inside this folder how to do it?

Comment: you can create folder by custom in res folder but android can not provide access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a folder in res folder and it named draw2 which i will use for specisific imageviews.

Custom folders in res folder are not supported. Better  To create [**`raw folder or asset folder`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) 
 for this purpose

**`raw/`**

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw `InputStream`, call `Resources.openRawResource()` with the resource ID, which is `R.raw.filename`.

[How to create assets in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315335/7666442)

[How to create raw in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777413/android-raw-folders-creation-and-reference)

for more information **[The Android Project View](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#mipmap)**

```
module-name/

    build/

    libs/

    src/
          androidTest/
          main/
                AndroidManifest.xml
                java/
                jni/
                gen/
                res/
                assets/
          test/
    build.gradle (module)
build.gradle (project)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Custom folders in res folder are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put the images you trying to access into your (**drawable**) folder, because in android the **res** folder has specific folder names like (**values**,**mipmap**,**anim**,**drawable** ...) , and you can't create new folder name , it will not be recognized.