# How to fix 'Class not found Exception' for a neural network file?

Tags: java, android, neural-network, ocr

As the new version of neuroph core is deprecated it is not able to load a neural network file named m.nnet which then throws an exception as shown:

**org.neuroph.core.exceptions.NeurophException: Class not found while trying to read neural network from file!
                      at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:638)**

the code which used to load this file was:

```
  InputStream irs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.m);
        net = NeuralNetwork.load(irs);
```

where m file is stored in raw folder.

now after following this link http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/neuroph/core/NeuralNetwork.html#load-java.lang.String-

they say that we need to use createFromFile() instead of load()

please help me to understand how to load the m.nnet file using createFromFile() method. Thank You!

Comment: One thing is for sure that exceptions are meant to be generate, so handle it within **try-catch block** for `ClassNotFoundException`. This is the least you can do.

Comment: Just to make sure. Is your `m` file in the `res/raw` folder?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777413/android-raw-folders-creation-and-reference

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann yes sir it is under res/raw folder it compiles properly and throws a runtime error then