# I am not able to access the raw folder containing audio and images

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to input some videos and audio into the app that I am making. Unfortunately, I am not able to access them when I put them in a newly created raw folder.

So I can view the folder on my navigation but can't access it. And I can also see it on windows explorer in the res directory. I tried putting these files in the drawable folder and I can access images but I am not able to access video or audio files.

Also, I tried cleaning the project (resulted in giving an error in R itself highlighting R with red.), creating a new project (resulted in the same error), created other folder names (since I am an amateur, I didn't know the significance of raw folder in apps. I realized other folder names I created didn't even appear on the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777413/android-raw-folders-creation-and-reference) is a really good post on raw folders in Android.

You should be able to access the raw folder provided that is nested inside the res folder. Also, the res folder has to be an android resource directory.

Hope this helps.